# Facebook UI behavior , iOS, sliding down imageview

Tags: iphone, xcode

I need to provide a sliding bar in xcode to alert the user that he entered wrong data.
I want it to appear for about 1 second at the top of the screen and then disappear, so something with animcation and commit, I have this code written for it and it kinda does the job, except that

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:.3];
CGPoint center = self.slidingView.center;
center.y += self.slidingView.frame.size.height;
self.errorLabel.center = center;
self.slidingView.center = center;
self.slidingView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0);

[UIView commitAnimations];

[self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.slidingView];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.errorLabel];
```

now the problrem with this is that initially the slidingview is hidden behind another UIView, but I need to make it just slide down, now this appears in a brute way( because of the call to bringSubviewToFront.

Any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you bring the subview to front before you make your animation calls?

Better yet, hide the view then bring subview to front. After that do a 'fade' animation in conjunction with the sliding animation you already have.

Comment: because I want it to slide form behind the control it is located behind, the bringtofront call just moves it up the z index.

Comment: Right. so if you call the bring subview to front at the beginning it shouldn't be as jarring (because the sliding view hasn't fully appeared yet)